# Drupal with frames

Tags: 7

I'm using Drupal 7 to create a musician's website. That musician would like to be able to play a sample of their music across multiple pages of the site without interruption. The only way I know to do this is to use frames. However, in the many sites I've used Drupal for, I've never used frames on a single Drupal site.

Has anybody else had experience with how to accomplish this?

EDIT: To clarify, the client wants an integrated music player within the site itself. Creating or finding a music player is easy. It's setting up to work with Drupal and not reload across pages that I don't know how to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just open new window via [js](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) and play it there. You can now navigate through site and music will play until you don't close certain window. So you should create page/node with player, create page template for it (you should remove showing block, menus,  etc in this) and point for js:window.open to that page.

Comment: That would indeed allow me to play music across pages, but it's not a very clean way of having an integrated media player in the site itself.

Comment: Frames are not a clean way to do anything. Frames are bad and dead. That's why you can't find a Drupal frame Site. http://www.google.ch/search?q=why+frames+are+bad If you don't want a Popup which is IMHO the best solution for you, you have to load your website content with an AJAX call. Therefore the page 'remains' the same while the Background music plays.

Comment: Not really a solution, but I talked the client into not caring.